# How to check programmatically whether a user is logged in to the app store

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I wanna check through my application whether any user is logged in to the app store or not. I am not sure whether apple provided any provision to check that. I guess store kit might help me but i am not sure.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that. StoreKit framework is only for providing in-app purchase functionality to your app. Not the status of user session with app store.

Comment: No. And there won't be in the near future too.